# enabling design view in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know where can I enable the bar that let me switch between different views (Design,split,..) in Visual Studio 2010 ? I can't find it and it is not enables by default

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you go into the Visual Studio Tools -> Options menu, under HTML Designer -> General there is a checkbox to enable or disable the HTML designer.  Checking this and restarting VS will do the trick and show the Design/Split/Source options at the bottom again.

I really prefer the Code Optimized setup but do need on occasion to hit the design view, shame it does not seem easier to expose and, when exposed, takes up more UI than it really needs to.

Comment: Of course, this doesn't apply to MVC apps. There is currently no way to view your HTML other than by running it in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Design/source tabs down in the bottom left corner of the window? (just above where your debug & immediate windows appear from in the default view). If you do, look further to the right of them, there is a splitter bar you can drag up to produce the split mode.

Answer (score 1):

It's a corrupt installation, try reintall the VS

Comment: :( it's true. happened on me. And I re-installed, everything good again.

Comment: It's absolutely, 100%, entirely, without any doubt whatsoever, the wrong answer to this question... as evidenced by the fact that a correct answer was accepted a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

I also cannot see the Design/Source tab split.  I could have sworn it was in VS2010 RC.  Did they take it out of retail?? (I'm working with an Activity xaml file)

Answer (score 0):

go to Tool->Option->General->Enabe Html Designer